# Private screen segue?

Tags: ios

I have a basic login/register field a user can use in my app. I want to also initiate a segue to a private screen: a new viewcontroller a user can see after the login/register button is tapped. I would appreciate if someone with experience with login in or registering in an app can help me programmatically specify a segue to a viewcontroller called UserViewController.

```
-(IBAction)btnLoginRegisterTapped:(UIButton*)sender {
//form fields validation
if (fldUsername.text.length < 4 || fldPassword.text.length < 4) {
    [UIAlertView error:@"Enter username and password over 4 chars each."];
    return;
}
//salt the password
NSString* saltedPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fldPassword.text, kSalt];
//prepare the hashed storage
NSString* hashedPassword = nil;
unsigned char hashedPasswordData[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
//hash the pass
NSData *data = [saltedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hashedPasswordData)) {
    hashedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashedPasswordData length:sizeof(hashedPasswordData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
} else {
    [UIAlertView error:@"Password can't be sent"];
    return;
}
//check whether it's a login or register
NSString* command = (sender.tag==1)?@"register":@"login";
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command", fldUsername.text, @"username", hashedPassword, @"password", nil];
//make the call to the web API
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:params onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {
    //result returned
    NSDictionary* res = [[json objectForKey:@"result"] objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([json objectForKey:@"error"]==nil && [[res objectForKey:@"IdUser"] intValue]>0) {
        [[API sharedInstance] setUser: res];
        [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        //show message to the user
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logged in" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome %@",[res objectForKey:@"username"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
    } else {
        //error
        [UIAlertView error:[json objectForKey:@"error"]];
    }
}];

}
```

Comment: what is `private ViewController`

Comment: What is a private view controller?

Comment: A viewcontroller in an application that a user can only see after loging in to the server.

Comment: Your pseudo code is incorrect in that it says to perform a segue to a "new view controller".  You perform a segue to a new scene based on the segue identifier for the segue in your storyboard.  It is the segue identifier that defines the destination scene and therefore the view controller that will be shown

Comment: any snippet? I have 0 experience here

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raywenderlich.com/81879/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-1

Check out that tutorial. You seem to be making things up as you go along - never a good way to learn.

There is no such thing as "private" view controller, what you have instead is a view controller which cannot be seen without a logon.

The flow you need is:

Setup auth view controler (username, password, [login] button)

Tie the login button to  a method

Put code in that method to check the validity of the credentials

if they are valid, present the new VC with a segue

Comment: I have successfully connected the IBOutlets/IBActions to a new viewcontroller for the username and password fields to a new application. I have also imported the api functionality. I was hoping you could help with the last step you outlined: 'if they are valid, present the new VC with a segue'

Comment: sure the app I'm working with was downloaded from the same site you posted. It has proprietary storyboard connections but I want a programatic methods so I can connect custom views and check for the initiated user method at my leisure. I know its an easy fix here somewhere...